# Horizontal Recyclerview inside Dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android app and want to show a Dialog when I click on any Button. I want to show some images in this Dialog box which will be scrolled horizontally. So, I have used a recyclerview with Horizontal scroll orientation to it's Linear Layout Manager.
But my images are shown one image at a time, to watch the second image in the Dialog box, I need to scroll horizontally. I want images to be shown till the wrap_content width and then start scrolling horizontally.

Please check the below code to create Dialog box :

```
Dialog reactionsDialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
                    reactionsDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    reactionsDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    reactionsDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,
                            R.drawable.shape));
                    RecyclerView reactionsRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(mContext);
                    reactionsDialog.setContentView(reactionsRecyclerView);
                    reactionsDialog.show();

                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                    reactionsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    reactionsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    reactionsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

It shows the first image in full width of the Dialog box and to see next image, I need to scroll horizontal. 
Please check the below attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

What should I do get it working. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make content view width wrap content.

Comment: Yes, I got a solution for this, thanks a lot for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced the same problem.**It was a problem of height and width of the items inside Horizontal RecyclerView.**

Refer the code below:

**horizontal_row.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleoffice"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:text="Kaustav"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The **recyclerview:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_horizontal">
 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: My issue was coming because of the match_parent width of the LinearLayout of recyclerview items, I have now changed the width to wrap_content and it is working fine now.

Comment: Yes that is the solution